# Flutter audioplayers error (1, -19) - No audio is played and the app doesn't crash

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use the flutter audioplayers package to play audio files and am getting this error. While following an online flutter tutorial I had this exact code and it ran and produced sound correctly, but now it doesn't play audio. I think maybe there is a change in my IDE settings or a change on my computer, but I don't know how to find the issue.

```
E/MediaPlayerNative(13949): error (1, -19)
E/MediaPlayer(13949): Error (1,-19)
E/MediaPlayerNative(13949): stop called in state 0, mPlayer(0xb4e843c0)
E/MediaPlayerNative(13949): error (-38, 0)
V/MediaPlayer(13949): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer(13949): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
V/MediaPlayer(13949): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer(13949): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
```

Here is the code I'm using to test the audioplayers package.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';

void main() => runApp(XylophoneApp());

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final player = AudioCache();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {
                player.play('note1.wav');
              },
              child: Text('Click Me'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts on this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
AudioCache audioCache = AudioCache();
String url = 'images/PID_meditation_demo_novoice.mp3';    //local mp3 file in asset folder

playLocal() async {
audioPlayer = await audioCache.play(url);      //audio play function
}

pauseAudio() async {                 // audio pause
await audioPlayer.pause();}

resumeAudio() async {
await audioPlayer.resume();                 //audio resume

}

stopAudio() async {
if(audioPlayer !=null){
await audioPlayer.stop();             //audio srope
}
}
```

Comment: So what exactly was the problem in the original question? I now also get the error `Error (1,-19)` when calling `await cache.load('tick.mp3'); await cache.play('tick.mp3')`

Comment: I have the same error after using the media player about ~30minutes and the sound is not heard anymore, even if the player was disposed and reintialized. After restarting the app, everthing works fine.

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issue , and no solution works for me , until i changed the package , check this one , it's very nice and works without any problem . [assets_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player)

```
    playQRScannerSound() async {
    AssetsAudioPlayer.newPlayer().open(
      Audio("assets/audios/scan_Beep.mp3"),
      autoStart: true,
    );
  }
```

I hope it help you , best of luck .

Comment: i wasn't able to get audioplayers working suddenly, so I switched to asset_audio_player as well.  Had been working fine for months.  Some update broke something.

Comment: I guess it can play any file from the device file system. I noticed that other Audio Players  saves a copy of the  selected file to a common folder like /data/user/0/com.example.example_application/cache/file_picker/    so I will set this folder as my assets folder. Lets hope it work for me too

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i actually have same error,
but i try this:

```
 final playerx = new AudioCache(fixedPlayer: AudioPlayer());
```

then on my action:

```
playerx.fixedPlayer.stop();
playerx.play('turn2.mp3');
```

i most stop stream my mplayer before i start it.
and that make error gone from the world..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've fixed your issue or not.  I had the same issue, The choice that I had and possibly yourself was to get a different package or connect your own phone instead of emulator, I found when I connected my own phone (galaxy note9) I had no problems anymore  .

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding "mode" and "stayAwake" as follows:

```
await audioPlayer.play("audio/buttonOn.mp3",
    mode: PlayerMode.LOW_LATENCY,
    stayAwake: false);
```